# Fokker-Planck approximation of birth-death process -- solution of non-linear ODE

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

I want to get the stationary state of the simple birth-death process using the Fokker-Planck expansion. This describes a population growing from births at rate $\lambda$ and shrinking from deaths at rate $\sigma$. The governing equations for the probabilities $P(n)$ that the population has size $n = 0,1,2,\dots$ are 
$$0 = \lambda P(n-1) + \sigma[n+1]P(n+1) - [\lambda + \sigma n]P(n).$$
Of course, this can be solved exactly for the Poisson distribution
$$ P(n) = \frac{(\lambda/\sigma)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda/\sigma},$$
but I would like to solve it approximately to gain familiarity with the Fokker-Planck equation.

To do this, I have attempted to treat $n$ as a continuous variable and expanded to second order in it, obtaining

$$ 0 \approx \lambda\Big[P - P' + \frac{1}{2}P''\Big] + \sigma\Big[ nP + (nP)' + \frac{1}{2}(nP)''\Big]- \Big[\lambda + \sigma n\Big]P$$
which simplifies to 
$$ 0 = \sigma P(n) + (\sigma [ n+1] -\lambda )P'(n) + \frac{1}{2}(\lambda + \sigma n)P''(n).$$

Unfortunately I do not know how to solve this non-linear ODE. Probably since $n\gg 1$ in the Fokker-Planck approximation, I can drop the $1$ in the second term and divide by $\sigma$ to obtain 
$$ 0  = P(n) + \Big(n - \frac{\lambda}{\sigma} \Big)P'(n) + \frac{1}{2}\Big(n + \frac{\lambda}{\sigma}\Big)P''(n).$$

Provided I'm on the right track (am I?), the solution of this should approximate the Poisson distribution.
Can anyone teach me how to show this?

Comment: It may not be constant coefficients, but that ODE is linear. In fact, it's linear and homogeneous. You might be able to use a series solution method. Mathematica yields $$P(n)=c_1 e^{-2 n} U\left(-\frac{4 l-s}{s},\frac{s-4
    l}{s}+1,\frac{2 l}{s}+2 n\right)+c_2 e^{-2 n} L_{\frac{4 l-s}{s}}^{\frac{s-4
    l}{s}}\left(\frac{2 l}{s}+2 n\right), $$ where the $U$ is the HypergeometricU function, and the $L$ is the LaguerreL function.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Probably a further large $n$ approximation needs to be made on the ODE I provided in order to get something more workable. The large $n$ limit of Poisson should be simply Gaussian. Naively I'd anticipate a result involving the Stirling approximation of $n!$ in the exact solution

Comment: Actually if you drop the 1 in the $P'$ term wolfram provides a much more manageable solution, but I'm not sure how to interpret it in comparison to the exact Poisson solution.